# Why are Tomcat's threads more costly than background threads?

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, asynchronous, threadpool

I am in reference to the following blog entry: [blog entry](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support/) about Spring MVC 3.2 asynchronous support.

I understand Tomcat uses a thread pool in order to serve http/web requests. Furthermore, the above article seems to indicate that **Spring MVC asynchronous support relieves Tomcat's thread pool** and **allows for better concurrency in the webapp by using background threads** for "heavy-lift" operations.

Can anyone please provide informed advice as to why that is? **Why is a "front-end" thread taken from the tomcat thread pool more costly than a background thread?**

Answer (score 0):

It's not 'more costly', but it's a relatively scarce resource used to process incoming requests, so doing other kinds of heavy lifting in them is contra-indicated.

Comment: If they are no more costly, then a naive approach could be just to increase the number of threads in the pool instead of using Spring async support?

Comment: Actually I am not absolutely sure the response is sent to the user more quickly (as would be the case with the service-level @Async annotation as opposed to the controller-level async support, which is what I am talking about here). I did try the provided sample and the browser actually hangs during the time of processing. The difference is that it is a background thread that does the processing. Do you see my point?